# Numpy - How to vectorize multiple transform matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of transform matrices to transform 3D points. I have about 62 [4x4] matrices basically.

Equivalently, I have 1 [4x1] 3D points.

Right, now I am interating through each transform, and applying the respective transform matrix to that same one point. Is there a way I can make use of Numpy's tensor representation to do this more cleanly?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
import numpy as np


transf = np.random.randint(1,9,(62,4,4))
points = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,62))

res = np.dot(transf,points)

print(res.shape)
print(res[0][:,0],np.dot(transf[0],points[:,0]))

# (62, 4, 62) -> (numb_transformation, point_coord, numb_of_points)
# [35 13 39 29] [35 13 39 29]
```

I took the first point to show that the result is the same.

This basically takes every matrix along the 0-axis of 'transf' and apply it to the array of 'points where' every column is a point so you have a shape (4,n_points)

The result will be an array where the first axis is the result of the application of the nth matrix, the second axis is the point coordinate and the 3rd axis is the number of the point

Comment: Ic, ok another issue. I did not mention this but i only have 1 3D point actually. I need to apply multiple transforms to that 1 point to get 62 points. I have had to edit my question to reflect it

Comment: This answer is very generic, you just take the 'points' array of shape (4,1)

Comment: Yes, but would I not have to convert that (4,1) point into a (4,62) point? It feels wasteful

Comment: No the result of a (62,4,4) dot (4,1) is a (62,4,1) where 62 is the number of the point generated by applying 62 matrices 4 is the coordinate and 1 coz you used just one point. If you don't like the shape you can add one step res = res[:,:,0] to get a 2D array where every row is a point and every column a coordinate

Comment: Ic, i will try and test it, if it works i will accept the answer